# What is system spacing in a layout?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm having difficulty understanding what "system spacing" or "standard spacing" between views are.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 500, height: 500))
rootView.backgroundColor = .white

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 300, height: 200)))
containerView.backgroundColor = .yellow
rootView.addSubview(containerView)

let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.backgroundColor = .red
containerView.addSubview(button)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: containerView.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1)
])

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView
```

I noticed that there is a difference if I substituted:

```
button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor)
```

for `equalToSystemSpacingAfter` in the position of the button. Also, how does `equalToSystemSpacingAfter` accommodate changes in the text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer to first question:

> difference between `constraint(equalTo:` & `.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter:`

[image]
[image]

#### Answer to second question:

> Also, how does equalToSystemSpacingAfter accommodate changes in the text size?

Since you are using fixed width of `100` points, so if the button title grows in length, it will be simply truncated. To solve the issue, you should avoid setting exact width of it.

Comment: Visual format notation's default spacing is also 8 so this makes sense.